# Intel RealSense SDK for 32 bit system

Tags: 32-bit, realsense

I want to know whether ' Intel RealSense SDK' is compatible only for 64 bit system or I can install it on 32 bit system.

Because I'm using a 32 bit system with windows 7(32-bit) OS.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (R4 release from August 2015) officially only supports Microsoft Windows 8.1 and 10 with 64-bit (https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/realsense/camera-sdk/v1.1/documentation/html/index.html?devguide_hardware_and_software_requirements.html).
However as just announced at IDF 2015 there will be support for more operating systems in the future (http://download.intel.com/newsroom/kits/idf/2015_fall/pdfs/Realsense_factsheet_IDF15.pdf), at least Linux and OS X, but maybe also Windows 7. But since 64-bit is the new industry standard it is questionable if there will be (official) support for 32-bit systems.

Comment: Thank you, but R2 will support 32-bit system :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can use the camera in windows 7 using the open source drivers. The only glitch is the color stream codec, which I was not able to find an install package for windows 7 yet. It comes with win8+ and refuses to install for win7.